# How to redirect from the index page to a route which is generated programmatically, in a Gatsby.JS project

Tags: gatsby, reach-router

I want to reroute the index `/` to `/blog` in a gatsby project. The page at `/blog` route is generated inside `gatsby-node.js` file.

What I tried is importing `Redirect` from `@reach-router` and inside the `Index` component returning `Redirect to='/blog'` but this results in `Uncaught RedirectRequest` error.

The `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect } from '@reach/router'


class BlogIndex extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Redirect to={`/blog`} />
    )
  }
}

export default BlogIndex
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [@reach/router docs](https://reach.tech/router/api/Redirect):

> Redirect works with componentDidCatch to prevent the tree from rendering and starts over with a new location.
>
> Because React doesn’t swallow the error this might bother you. For example, a redirect will trigger Create React App’s error overlay. In production, everything is fine. If it bothers you, add **noThrow** and Redirect will do redirect without using componentDidCatch.

Add a `noThrow` tag seems to solve this:

```
<Redirect noThrow to="/topath" />
```

---

You could also ask Gatsby to do this for you, in `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.createPages = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createRedirect } = actions

  createRedirect({
    fromPath: `/`,
    toPath: `/topath`,
    redirectInBrowser: true,
    isPermanent: true,
  })
}
```

See [more here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/445f5ff7508ab613967e18b32490e3feffd7730c/examples/using-redirects/gatsby-node.js).

---

I'd add this redirect rule to where the site is hosted as well.

Answer (score 10):

Use this instead. The `useEffect` is the React hook equivalent to componentDidMount.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { navigate } from 'gatsby';

export default () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigate('/blog/');
  }, []);
  return null;
};
```